# Exercises about series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, divergent-series

Using the Cauchy criterion,specify the nature of the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{k+1}{3k+2}=$$

Study the convergence(or divergence) of this series with positive terms
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt[3]{k+1}-\sqrt[3]{k}}{k^2}=$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$ \frac{k+1}{3k+2} \to \frac13$$

therefore the series diverges and

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{k+1}-\sqrt[3]{k}}{k^2}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{(k+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(k+1)k}+\sqrt[3]{k^2}}{k^2}=\frac{3k^\frac23}{k^2} \sim \frac{1}{ k^\frac43}$$

therefore the series converges by limit comparison test with $\sum \dfrac{1}{ k^\frac43}$.